# List of listings - how to add

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I have defined listings. How to create a list of listings? I mean something similar to `\listoftables`. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter]{\mylisting}[2][]{listing file={#2},title=Listing,colback=white,colframe=gray!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,breakable,title=Soubor \thetcbcounter: #1}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}   

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{code.txt}    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of code fragments.

Comment: I editted my question

Answer (score 8):

Here is the `tcolorbox` - way to generate list of 'something', here list of listings with the settings `list type=...` and `list  inside`.

The `title=...` is used by default for inserting the name of the entry.

`\tbclistof[\chapter*]{lol}{\lstlistingname}` is the `tcolorbox` - way of saying `\listof....`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[2][]{%
  listing file={#2},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title=Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2,
  #1
}


\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}   


\begin{document}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{lol}{\lstlistingname}
\clearpage
\mylisting{helloworldexample.c}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

The `helloworldexample.c` file follows

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}


\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}   


\begin{document}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{lol}{\lstlistingname}
\clearpage
\mylisting{Some caption}{helloworldexample.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you and what is this ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ ... file.txt}}{27}{tcb@cnt@mylisting.1} ? There should be some $?

Comment: @Elisabeth: Sorry, I don't understand. My example runs without problems, having the newest TL 2018 installed, i.e. updated daily

Comment: Yes, it runs, but when I give in into a original code, there is this error

Comment: @Elisabeth: I don't understand what you mean -- I don't see what you have done actually in your code.

Comment: Is this right? 
`\tcblistof[\chapter*]{lol}{\lstlistingname}

\clearpage

\mylisting[Vstupní soubor programu \texttt{input}, label=input]{input.txt}`

I mean the parameters in [ ].

Comment: `\mylisting[title={Vstupn...},label=input]{input.txt}`. `Vstupni` is no parameter and `tcolorbox` would complain. Please read the manual!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87809/discussion-between-elisabeth-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: Where to add label here? `\tcblistof[\chapter*]{lol}{\lstlistingname}
\clearpage
\mylisting{Some caption}{helloworldexample.c}`

Comment: @Elisabeth: `\mylisting[label=somelabel]{Some caption}{helloworldexample.c}`. -- It's all described in the manual :-(

Comment: Thank you and please the last question - I have a lstlistingname on the right place but nothing below it and a few pages back I have a lstlistingname with the list of listings. What is the problem please?

Comment: @Elisabeth: Of course you can not use **both** `\tcblistof` and `\lstlistoflistings` (order does not matter). Regardless which comes first, it will close the `.lol` file and rewrite it, leaving it empty. The second macro  will then open an empty file just print the heading...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\lstlistoflisting` that is introduced by the `listings` package:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter]{\mylisting}[2][]{listing file={#2},title=Listing,colback=white,colframe=gray!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,breakable,title=Soubor \thetcbcounter: #1}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}   

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=test]
content of the listing
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the [listings manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

> `\lstlistoflistings`
>   prints  a  list  of  listings.   Each  entry  is  with  descending  priority  either  the short caption, the caption, the file name or the name of the listing, [...]

If you want to change the heading of the list of listings from 'Listings' to something else, you can use `\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{<new title>}`

Comment: Thank you very much and how to set an another name instead of "Listings" .

Comment: Btw, `\lstinputlisting` takes caption as an argument: `\lstinputlisting[caption=test]{code.txt}`

Comment: @Elisabeth: Regarding the different title for the list of listings, please see the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know where is mistake but I have only the New title (Listings) in the final file. When I compile your code separately it works well. Is it problem that codes are in \include{kap00}?