# Setting space and font in tcbinputlisting

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

How to set a space above the `\mylisting`   and is the fontsize set fine? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}     
\begin{document}
\begin{footnotesize}
\mylisting[label=h]{h}{h.txt}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is the fontsize set fine?"

Comment: `footnotesize` is no environment.

Comment: Please post compilable examples -- there is no information about `h.txt` available. And you have answers to your other questions, please consider to accept them!

Comment: I don't understand what `a space` above should mean? Some empty vertical space, i.e. something like `\medskip`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font in `listings` is controlled by `basicstyle` etc. Since the question uses the `listings` library of `tcolorbox`, the style must be given as `listing option={basicstyle={...}}` as an option to the `\mylisting` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}   
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}   

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  listing options={basicstyle=\footnotesize\listingsfont},
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  listing only,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  breakable,
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}




\begin{document}
\mylisting[label=foo]{Some caption}{helloworldexample.c}
\end{document}
```

The file `helloworldexample.c` can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468331/31729) (This question is a follow-up, actually!)

[image]