# Font size in listing

Tags: listings, fontsize, tcolorbox

How to set a font size in listing when I have these settings in the preamble?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny} 

\begin{document}
\mylisting[label=s]{s}{s.txt}
 \end{document}
```

File `s.txt`:

```
x = 5;<br>
y = 6;<br>
z = x + y;
```

I tried

```
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  fontsize=\footnotesize,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
```

There is an error and

```
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny}
```

that does not do anything - the font size remains the same.

Comment: can you provide full MWE, i.e., from \documentclass{...}...\end{document}

Comment: I am sorry I editted the question

Comment: The file is there

Comment: @Elisabeth Why are you posting the same question again, giving not the slightest feedback to the solution of the other one or accepting it? I clearly wrote there that you need `listing options={basicstyle=\footnotesize\listingsfont}` and `fontsize` is no option of `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already explained by [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) in his answer to [Setting space and font in tcbinputlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468511/35864), the font style (including size and font family) for the code display can be set with `basicstyle` in `listings`. In an `tcolorbox` environment options to `listings` can be passed on with `listing option`, so that we end up with

```
listing options={basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily},
```

In total

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
x = 5;
y = 6;
z = x + y;
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  listing options={basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily},
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\mylisting{Lorem}{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: A listings colorbox with <code>\tiny</code> font.]

I must say that I find `\tiny` a wee bit hard to read, `\scriptsize` or `\footnotsize` is probably the smallest I would go (with the usual settings). You may also want to adjust the margins a bit so that the code does not get overwhelmed by the vast space around it.